# How to check whether the entered mobile is landline or mobile using PhoneFormat.js?

Tags: javascript

This is my example form. I just have take one text box, where I will enter mobile number and I will choose the country from the drop-box menu, for validating the mobile number with country I have used the http://www.phoneformat.com/. Here they have given one method `isValidNumber(phno, country)` which validate the phone number with the country (both landline number and mobile number).

My requirement is I need to allow only mobile number, for that I have used the `getNumberType(phno)`, but it is not giving any results, can anyone help me how to check whether the entered number is landline or mobile number?

```
<form name="fm" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="phno" id="phno"> <br>
<select id="Ultra"> 
     <option value="0">Select</option>
     <option value="IN">India</option>
     <option value="AU">Australia</option>
     <option value="CN">China</option>
     <option value="US"> America </option>
</select><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="check" onclick="run()">

</form>


<script>
function run()
{

var phoneUtil = i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

var phno = document.getElementById("phno").value;
alert('Phone number is '+phno);

 var res=isValidNumber(phno, country);

var country=document.getElementById("Ultra").value;

alert('Country code is '+country);

try{

    var res1=getNumberType(phno);

    alert('type of phone number is '+res1);

    }catch(e){

    alert(e);
}



alert("validation result is "+res);

}

</script>
```

Comment: can u just show us the code for getPhoneNumberType method

Comment: http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html i have found here getNumberType() but it is not  found in the PhoneFormat.js and google PhoneUtil.js

Comment: r u getting values in res variable or is it coming as undefined or null? and one more thing which country this not working i mean for all or for particular country

Comment: I m getting result for res correctly, but I am not getting the undefinedError for res1.

Comment: Why not use the underlying lib directly instead of using a script which doesn't add anything?

Comment: Which country u have selected?

Comment: 1234567890 is mobile number i have entered and choose india

Comment: Then What is coming in res1?

Comment: You could use an API to send the user a text message - though I think landlines in some countries can receive them now.

Comment: I am using that one only not getting any result

Comment: @SundarRajan its not showing alert for it

Comment: @ASR what is coming in res1 variable undefined or null?

Comment: its not showing any thing..

Comment: @SundarRajan can you create one room for us? i will explain my problem clearly...

Comment: @ASR well unfortunately i can't with my reputation

Comment: @ASR temme this what is coming in variable res1 so that everyone can understand your problem

Comment: @SundarRajan come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65215/discussion-between-asr-and-sundar-rajan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have created my own method and included in the phoneFormat.js (http://www.phoneformat.com/) for MOBILE it will give 1, for FIXED_LINE it will give 0.

function isMobileNumber(phone, country) {
            /*

```
        Tests whether number the given number is Mobile or not.

        */

        //alert('hello isMobileNumber()');

        try {
            var phone = cleanPhone(phone);
            var phoneUtil = i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            var number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(phone, country);

           // alert('hello isMobileNumber'+phoneUtil.getNumberType(number));

            if(phoneUtil.getNumberType(number)==1){

                return true;
            }
            return false;

            } catch (e) {

                alert(e);
            //return false;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for

```
var res1= phoneUtil.getNumberType(phno);
```

Hope this will work